# MYSQL select field1, field2 only where field1 or field2 does not equal text

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, mysqli

I have the following 2 SQL syntax that I'm looking to combine into 1 SQL syntax

```
SELECT sentFrom 
FROM tableName 
WHERE id = :varid 
AND sentFrom != :vartext

SELECT sentTo 
FROM tableName 
WHERE id = :varid 
AND sentTo != :vartext
```

I guess I should give an example:

MYSQL TABLE

```
-----------------------------------
sentFrom          sentTo
1                 2
1                 3
2                 1
2                 3
```

query

```
select sentFrom where sentFrom != 1 and select sentTo where sentTo != 1
```

Returns:

sentTo 2 but not sentFrom 1

sentTo 3 but not sentFrom 1

sentFrom 2 but not sentTo 1

sentFrom 2 and sentTo 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should help.

```
SELECT a.sentFrom , b.sentTo FROM 
 (SELECT id, sentFrom FROM tableName WHERE id = :varid AND sentFrom != :vartext) a
JOIN 
 (SELECT id, sentTo FROM tableName WHERE id = :varid AND sentTo != :vartext) b
ON a.id = b.id;
```

If you think, `ID` is not common in the rows selected in each query then remove the join condition `ON a.id = b.id`. In that case it will return you the `Cartesian product` of records of query one to query 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Syntex of select query is :
 Select Colname1,Colname2,.... from tablename 
        where colname=value and/or ...
        group by cond..
        having cond...
        order by colname, colname asc/desc
======================================
Ex:

  SELECT sentFrom,sentTo  FROM tableName
       WHERE id = :varid AND (sentFrom != :vartext or sentTo != :vartext)
```

Comment: the column contains both sentFrom and sentTo but if in a given column sentFrom = the var text i want it to still extract the sentTo not just skip over it

Comment: SELECT sentFrom,sentTo  FROM tableName
       WHERE id = :varid AND (sentFrom != :vartext or sentTo != :vartext or commom_colname != :vartext)                                      Here commmon colname is common columnname those include both value.